# Navbar overlapping content in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My portfolio page has a sticky navbar, but when I click on the navbar links it overlaps the text in each section. In about, it overlaps the text. In "portfolio" and "about" it overlaps both tiles. I tried to compensate with some padding-top in each section to no avail.

Here is the complete navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded fixed-top" style="background-color: #fc7a57;">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto navfont" href="#">portfolio.</a>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#about"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> about</a>
                </li>

              <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text" href="#portfolio"><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> portfolio</a>
              </li>

              <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text" href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> contact</a>
              </li>

           </ul>
    </nav>
```

And here's the CSS code for one of the sections

```
 #contact {
  background-color: #466365;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top:50px;
  color: white;
}
```

https://codepen.io/pablovester/pen/ZKJxLL

Thank you guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing wrong I see is you are using ID's to style elements, NO, use class. 
You are using ID "portfolio" in more than 1 element while Id should be unique in document.
Anyway to fix your problem just add `margin-top: 100px;` will be enough

```
.portfolio {
  background-color: #bcd39c;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top:50px;
  margin-top:100px;
}
```

and add a class in html

```
<div id="portfolio" class="portfolio">
```

and also in other needed IDS.
Hope it helps!
I'm working on this site and did exactly what you are trying to achieve, [check it out](https://karate-santa-pola.firebaseapp.com/)

Comment: ¡Hola Adolfo! ¡Gracias! (Escribiré el resto en inglés para que todos entiendan)

The padding top solved the thing but most importantly, I'll pick your id and class comments for the future, to write nice and clean code. Thank you!

Comment: Me alegra haberte podido ayudar aunque mi inglés sea flojito.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this HTML source and check if help you. Don't forget to copy all links at CSS and Javascript Settings section.

https://codepen.io/danogliari/pen/gWQWqo

```
<nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Daniel Ogliari</a>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#profile">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this same problem in Bootstrap 4 is...

```
.navbar-nav > .nav-item > a {
position: relative; 
}
```